# Sending JSON from python script to JQuery

Tags: jquery, python, html, json, ajax

I am a newbie to Jquery and my script below doesn't produce any output on the HTML page.

**Problem**:

Within my script, I use the `requests` library to send a GET request to a Flask URL that returns a JSON object. This object then needs to be sent to the JQuery which would then output the JSON object on a webpage. If I send the data using `response.text` it works fine, but if I send it using `response.json()` it outputs nothing. However I would need it to be sent as a JSON object so that I could then extract all the data out of it and put it on the HTML elements.

**getajaxtest.py**:

```
import requests
import json
def send_log_ajax():
     url = 'http://xx.com/returnjsonobj'
     response = requests.get(url)
     return response.json()
if __name__ == '__main__':
     ajax_var = send_log_ajax()
     print(ajax_var)
```

**the HTML and JQuery**:

```
 <html>
    <head><script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script></head>
    <body>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;background-color:lightgray">
        <p id="transactioninfo">Loading Transaction Information...</p>
    </div>
    <script>
    function getlogs() {

    var url = 'www.myserver.com/getajaxtest.py';

        $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: url,
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data) {

           $("#transactioninfo").html(data)
        },

        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });

    }
    $(document).ready(function(){

        setTimeout(function(){getlogs();}, 2000);
        setInterval(function(){getlogs();}, 2000);

    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing a **Python** data structure, not JSON. `requests.json()` decoded the Flask response to Python dictionaries, lists, strings, numbers, booleans, and perhaps `None`. That's not JSON data.

Just keep your data as JSON data, and print the text you received. Your script is nothing but a proxy, there is no need to interpret the JSON data.

If you must decode (perhaps you wanted to apply some transformations to the data contained), make sure you *encode back to JSON again*. Use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to produce a new JSON-encoded string when you do.

Comment: Shall I just use `response.text` and then within JQuery, use `dataType: 'json'`? And nope, no transformations are required, I just need to extract the values from the keys within Jquery

Comment: @omrakhur: then just print `response.text` for Unicode text, or write `response.content` directly to `sys.stdout.buffer` to avoid decoding from bytes and encoding back again.

Comment: I'm a bit confused between `response.content` and `response.text`. If I use the former, would it still be seen as JSON when the thing is returned to JQuery?

Comment: @omrakhur: `response.content` is the raw response from the server, as bytes. JSON is a text-based format, so you can decode the bytes as text. That's what the `response.text` value is, the bytes interpreted through a text encoding (usually UTF-8 for JSON).

Comment: @omrakhur: writing out text with `print()` has to encode that text again, as files (including a terminal or a network connection) only take bytes. So your JSON text is encoded again to bytes, and the encoding *could* be different. So for the same JSON data you could end up with a different result. You don't specify how you run your Python script (is it a CGI script perhaps?) so it's unclear what encoding would be used. It could just be ASCII, and I know Flask produces ASCII-safe JSON, so it *probably* all is fine.

Comment: Thank you. Just for any one who's wondering, I my ajax call was like so after Martijn's advice: 
`$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
       var jsonobj = $.parseJSON(data)

       $("#transactioninfo").html(jsonobj['message'])`